# Rendering internally linked markdown files in django

Tags: django, markdown

I want to link to markdown pages in a markdown page served by django. For example, in a markdown page index.md, I have a link

```
 [link label](path/page1.md)
```

But when I click the link, I don't get the rendered page (as I intended).  In stead I get the option to download the file.  The markdown page index.md is rendered as expected.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What views are you using to serve the mark down pages? It could potentially be that your browser is interpreting the `.md` extension as a file and therefore download.

Comment: I only tried IE. But I believe it's due to rendering (django server doesn't render the md file into html file).  I don't think IE would be able to turn a md file into a html file for displaying.